# HTML5-Videos sometimes not working in IE11,10 and 9

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-11

I exchanged the Flash-videos of an old website with new html5 video tags. They look like this:

```html
<video width="129" height="97" autoplay loop>
   <source src="index_dateien/animationen/iw_kurvengetriebe_160x120_112.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   <source src="index_dateien/animationen/iw_kurvengetriebe_160x120_112.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

There are many videos like this on one page. In Chrome and Firefox it works fine, also when I open the website in Internet Explorer from my local harddrive it works perfectly fine. But after uploading it to my webspace, randomly some of the videos won't load and are displayed as black squares. Everytime I refresh the page, different videos arent loading, sometimes all load, sometimes not a single one is displayed correctly. I'm running the latest Version of IE on Windows 7 Pro and my internet connection is fast enough. The problem also occurs on another computer with the same version of IE. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?  Thank you

Comment: have you tried putting the mp4 option first? there's also a limit to the number of connections the browser can have open over http so if you have 'autoplay' on all of them you may be hitting that limit... try starting at 1 and adding them back 1 at a time until you hit the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the .ogg format. Internet Explorer and Edge don't support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogv

Sometimes it probably loads the other version which is why it works occasionally.

Does it work if you remove the .ogg format?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem.